# Parameterized External Content Types?

Tags: external-content-type, external-list

Suppose I have multiple instances of some line of business app in my environment. Is there a way to create a single External Content Type that can be parametrized and reused? If I have 5 instances, is it necessary to create 5 external lists and 5 external content types, or can the lists indicate which data source should be used?

Comment: can you give an example (in business terms) of how these content types would be parameterized?

Comment: Can I have a single Extenal Content Type called 'customer' when the California customers are in a db on one server and the New York customers are in another? Can the target of a ECT be parameterized as long as the schema is identical?

Comment: oh, I get it - same schema, different database connections.  That's a great question. I would probably just create the separate ECTs, but I'd be interested to hear if there is a solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach in this case would be to do the CRUD routing at the web-service/stored procedure level.

Alternatively you could write the models in Visual Studio and build logic into the CRUD methods to determine where the record should end up.

Depends where you feel more comfortable placing your business logic, if this is going to be common practice then I would say webservice.